# ciphers depend on Elliptic curve cryptography

Tags: elliptic-curves

IS there any cipher dependent on the Elliptic curve cryptography?
and it is Accredited by any  origanization like RSA or El GAMAL

Which are the ciphers depend on the Elliptic curve cryptography?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. [ElGamal encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption) can be instantiated with Elliptic Curve Cryptography. That's essentially the asymmetric cryptography part of [ECIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme), which adds symmetric cryptography to become [CCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-ciphertext_attack)-resistant. ECIES has wide endorsement, e.g. [in SEC1 v2](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=41), [ANSI X9.63](https://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ANSI%20X9.63-2011%20(R2017)), IEEE 1363a, [ISO/IEC 18033-2](https://www.iso.org/standard/37971.html).